# Hosting website in Azure and Using sql Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure

I build an ASP.NET website on Visual Studio Community 2013, Using SQL Server database in C#.

I want To host it in Microsoft Azure.
I sign in Microsoft Azure and publish my site on it.

When I try to select row from my database I get that error:

```
Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]

[SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
```

My connectionString is:

```
string connStr = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDBFilename=""C:\Users\MyComp\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test\Test\App_Data\MyDB.mdf"";Integrated Security=True";
```

My Database have windows authentication

What and how I need to change to make this reading from db work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your connection string to:

```
Server=tcp:[serverName].database.windows.net;Database=[myDataBase];
User ID=[LoginForDb]@[serverName];Password=[myPassword];Trusted_Connection=False;
Encrypt=True;
```

Where `[serverName]` is your server name and etc.

Comment: Make sure that you allow access to Azure services to your database: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/

Answer (score 0):

From your connection string, you are actually pointing to the SQL database server on your localhost.

Your Azure web app would not know how to locate your localhost SQL database server and the attached DB file (.mdf).

This is one solution:

1. Create a new SQL database on Azure, which will automatically create a new SQL server
2. Migrate your local SQL database to Azure SQL database created above. Refer to [Migrating a SQL Server database to Azure SQL Database](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-cloud-migrate/)
3. Note that Azure SQL database DOES NOT support Windows Authentication. You could look for alternative such as using Azure Active Directory Authentication [Connecting to SQL Database By Using Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/) or SQL Server Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Once you create an Azure SQL database it will provide you with the connection string you need for your application. go to the Dashboard of your SQL Azure DB and on the right side you will see "Show connection strings"

For clarity you cannot use a .mdf database with Azure Web Apps, you would need to create a Virtual Machine. Best option is to use Web Apps with SQL Azure database.